# Fetch 2 values using selectrow_array in Perl

Tags: mysql, arrays, perl, fetch

I recently figured that there is a `selectrow_array` function to fetch values from databases. I'm getting following error when I'm using it. I wonder what is the issue here and couldn't find an alternative way to do this.

Code is:

```
my $db_connection = DBI->connect($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpassword ) or die $DBI::errstr;

my $sql_statement = "SELECT customer_id,quota FROM customer_call_quota WHERE quota>=1";

while (my $row = $db_connection->selectrow_array($sql_statement)) {
     my ($cust_id, $quota) = @$row; #<---- error line
 }

my $rc = $db_connection->disconnect ;
return "ok";
```

Error:

```
Can't use string ("value") as an ARRAY ref while "strict refs" in use at code.pl line ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two problems.

- `selectrow_array` doesn't return a reference to an array. That's `selectrow_arrayref`.
- `selectrow_*` only returns the first row.

Solutions:

```
# Wasteful

my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql_statement);
$sth->execute();
while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    my ($cust_id, $quota) = @row;
    ...
}
```

or

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql_statement);
$sth->execute();
while (my ($cust_id, $quota) = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
    ...
}
```

or

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql_statement);
$sth->execute();
while (my $row = $sth->fetch()) {
    my ($cust_id, $quota) = @$row;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ah, its only returns the first row. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes, but it's actually the other problem that resulted in the error you got